# Arraylist of json formatted string with Jmeter issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jmeter

How to request a Spring rest method with a parameter of array of `json` formatted string in `Jmeter`?
e.g.
if I use send parameters with the request

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},{"key3":"value3","key4":"value4"}
```

It is triggering the `Rest` method but it is not taking it as a two values it is taking as a four values.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/createDemand",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public restResponse createDemand(@RequestParam("sessionId") String sessionId,
                                     @RequestParam("loggedInEmpId") String loggedInEmpId,
                                     @RequestParam(name = "demandList[]") ArrayList<String> demandList,
                                     @RequestParam("isNewDemand") String isNewDemand
                                     ) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException{
```

It is triggering the Rest API,But it is splitting the json object,I passed two json object and Rest API accepts only array of json strings.This is working fine when I JSON.stringify it from javascript and call this using ajax.
And this is returning json parser exception.

Sampler
[Sampler image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeWbz.jpg)

HTTP Header Manager
[HTTP Header Manager image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83mrv.jpg)

Thank you. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the http method used  and what you want to send . Please provide more info and share some code

Comment: if you are simulating in the JMeter, try as follows: `[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},{"key3":"value3","key4":"value4"}]` in the body section of HTTP Request and add `content-type` as `application/json` in `HTTP Header Manager` for that request.

Comment: @Naveen with application/json  it is showing bad request and one parameter is null in path.

Comment: please add Test Plan screen shots highlighting the errors and what you are expecting